# A flow layout container in win8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, windows-8, stackpanel

I have a few items inner a `GridView`, I hope they locates like:

```
<-------              fixed size: 600                 --------->
[     Item 1, lengh 300        ][       Item 2, lengh 300      ]
[ Item 3, lengh 200 ][ Item 4, lengh 200 ][ Item 5, length 200 ]
[    Item 6, Length 400                  ][ Item 7, length 200 ]
```

Now I need to choose a container as `GridView.ItemsPanel`. A `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />` won't start a new line automatically. `VariableSizedWrapGrid` and `WrapGrid` can limit the items in a fixed width, but all cells/items have the same width. Is there a container can do this?

Comment: VariableSizedWrapGrid is the right panel to use in your case

Comment: @Denis: I tried `VariableSizedWrapGrid`, but all cells have the same width. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I need help with this as well.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen: At last I gave up using `GridView`, fortunately there are 7 items only so they are located manually in three `StackPanel`s.

Comment: There is hope Danny. I spent the last couple of hours making my own. I shared the code with you. Hope it forefills your needs!

Answer (score 2):

I programmed [my own FlowPanel](http://pastebin.com/YDstvwhr). It works quite well, and produces the following result.

[image]

If you are curious, that's my StackOverflow app for Windows 8 called Stackstabilizer which releases soon.